# Unix domain socket firewall

Tags: linux, apache, ipc

I've got a problem with my debian server.
Probably there is some vulnerable script at my web-serser, which is running from www-data user.
I also have samba with winbind installed, and samba is joined to windows domain.

So, probably this vulnerable script allows hacker to bruteforce out domain controller through winbind unix domain socket.

Actually I have lots of such lines at netstat -a output:

unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     509027   /var/run/samba/winbindd_privileged/pipe

And our DC logs contain lots of recorded authentication attems from root or guest accounts.

How can I restrict my apaches access to winbind?
I had an idea to use some kind of firewall for IPC sockets. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unix domain sockets use the file system for endpoints, therefore you can use POSIX file permissions or ACLs to restrict access.

Actually answered before here:  [AF_UNIX domain - why use local file names only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783134/af-unix-domain-why-use-local-file-names-only)

Answer (score 0):

You can't firewall `AF_UNIX` sockets.  I would expect the real problem is that some login form on your web server allows brute force attempts, and should be rate-limited somehow (maximum number of attempts, timeouts, etc.).